# Thunderbird 52.5.2 Calendar 'Provider for Google' (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird, google-calendar

## CONTEXT

Attempting to troubleshoot why a fresh install of Thunderbird 52.5.2 [outfitted with 'Provider for Google Calnder 3.3'](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar#w_read-and-write-access) is unable to write to Google Calendar.

## QUESTION

The screenshot below indicates 0.31 AND 0.25 USERS. Am I a '3.3' user?  If not, how do I determine this number for my configuration?  If you have had success configuring your instance of Thunderbird to WRITE to a Google calendar **please state this in your reply**.

> NOTE FOR 0.31 AND 0.25 USERS After a previous announcement, Google has
>   shut down the v1 API on November 17th, 2014. Version 0.32 and 0.25
>   have been using this API. As a result, those versions will no longer
>   work and you MUST upgrade to 1.0.x to continue using the Provider for
>   Google Calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in your screenshot says "Provider for Google Calendar 3.3". You are a 3.3 user.

(I have write access to my Google Calendars, but I'm not in a fresh install, I have them set up in Thunderbird since ages, so this information may be irrelevant here. Anyway, checking the added calendars' properties about the read only checkbox may help.)

Comment: Please consider posting your Thunderbird and Provider versions in the response.  Thank you

Comment: My Thunderbird version is 52.5.0 (32-bit) and my Provider version is 3.3. I don't see how those are relevant though, as I have no idea about the versions I used when setting up Thunderbird with Google Calendar.

Comment: Based on your current config, I would have greater confidence that a  fresh 52.5.0 with Provider 3.3 has a good probability of working (writing), though there are no guarantees because these are not the original install versions